# Problemas de conversión de texto a fecha en excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un formulario que permite facilitar el ingreso de datos de una tabla. Tiene diferentes textbox, y deseo que tengan diferentes formatos. Pero cuando coloco los formatos y se presiona el botón para insertar en la hoja se ponen como formato de texto.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Dim i, fila As Long
Dim Actividad As Worksheet

' Definimos la hoja "BD-Actividades" en la variable Actividad
Set Actividad = Sheets("BD-Actividades")
' Definimos la fila en donde colocaremos los nuevos datos: Columna A, final de última fila
fila = Actividad.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Formato de los cuadros
Me.FechaText.Value = CDate(Me.FechaText)
Range("A" & fila).Value = Format(Me.FechaText.Value, "Short Date")

' Por cada cantidad de filas en el ListBox repetirá los siguientes datos
For i = 0 To Me.ListBoxVoluntario.ListCount - 1
    Actividad.Cells(fila, 1) = Me.FechaText
    fila = fila + 1
Next i

Call LimpiarActividad ' Llamar la función LimpíarActividad  para vaciar casillas

MsgBox " Ha sido cargado completamente", vbInformation, "Carga completada"

End Sub
```

Comment: La [Función Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) siempre va a devolver un **String**, es decir, un texto. Cuando ejecutas `Range("A" & fila).Value = Format(Me.FechaText.Value, "Short Date")` le estás diciendo que lo ponga como texto.

Comment: esto puede ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747863/how-to-force-the-input-of-a-textbox-on-a-userform-to-be-a-specific-format-in-vba

Comment: ¡Bienvenido Norielka a Stack Overflow en español! Tómese un tiempo para leer la recorrido a Stack Overflow en español y obtenga su primera medalla. Somos un poco diferentes de otros sitios. Así es como... https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour